# SQL incorrect difference calculation between a value and a column average

Tags: sql, mysql, average, calculation

So I wrote a query to find  a list of countries' GDP in 2022 with a difference from average GDP among them for each country. But when I checked the calculations, the difference values were wrong so i added (gdp_value - 0) calculation column and it showed that the GDP used for (gdp_value - average) calculation is different from the actual GDP value. Can someone please explain why SQL uses a different value for calculation?

here's the SQL code:

```
select
    rank() over(order by gdp_value desc) as 'rank',
    country_name,
    gdp_value,
    (gdp_value - 0) as gdp_test,
    average,
    (gdp_value - average) as difference
from gdp, (select avg(gdp_value) as average
            from gdp
            where country_code in
                (select code
                from world.country
                where continent = 'Africa')
                    and year = '2022') subq
where country_code in
    (select code
    from world.country
    where continent = 'Africa')
        and year = '2022'
group by country_name, gdp_value, average
order by gdp_value desc;
```

here's the results i'm getting :

| rank | country_name | gdp_value | gdp_test | average | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nigeria | 477000000000 | 477000007680 | 56499913809.23077 | 420500093870.7692 |
| 1 | Egypt, Arab Rep. | 477000000000 | 477000007680 | 56499913809.23077 | 420500093870.7692 |
| 3 | South Africa | 406000000000 | 406000009216 | 56499913809.23077 | 349500095406.7692 |
| 4 | Algeria | 192000000000 | 192000000000 | 56499913809.23077 | 135500086190.76923 |
| 5 | Morocco | 134000000000 | 134000001024 | 56499913809.23077 | 77500087214.76923 |

(sorry for bad visualisation, i don't know how else to do it here)

(i tried `cast(gdp_value as decimal(15,2))` suggested in one of the questions here but it just makes 'gdp_value' the same as 'gdp_test', but i still don't understand how to calculate the difference with the actual gdp_value)

Comment: Can you tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: Please add the DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;`) and some sample data to your question. It looks like you are storing your `gdp_value` as a float - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9qkMVbQb). [You might find this a useful read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14637565/). **Note:** casting to int or decimal does not magically restore the precision lost when storing your values as floats.

Comment: @user1191247 yes, it was indeed stored as float, i already understood the issue and changed data type to decimal. thanks for information about float.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your `cast(gdp_value as decimal(15,2))` worked, means this is the answer. That means you have to use that every single place where you use gpd_value, which of course can be a pain.

For example:
`avg(gdp_value)` becomes `avg(cast(gdp_value as decimal(15,2)))`

If your SQL engine supports Common Table Expressions (CTEs) - this is an alternative style to writing SQL that I think will benefit you here. First, it is easier to debug and read. Second, you can build upon yourself so that when you encounter things like this, you only have to fix the gdp_value once and then the rest build upon it.

For example, perhaps something like this:

```
WITH gdp_fixed AS (
    SELECT code, country_name, cast(gdp_value as decimal(15,2)) AS gdp_value
    FROM gpd
),
countries AS (
    SELECT distinct code
    FROM world.country
    WHERE continent = 'Africa'
    AND year='2022'
),
-- instead of an IN() I am just joining, but you can do either
gpd_filtered AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM gdp_fixed A
    INNER JOIN countries B
    ON A.country_code = B.code
),
averages AS (
    SELECT avg(gpd_value) AS average
    FROM gpd_filtered
),
merged AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM gdp_filtered, averages
)
SELECT rank() over(order by gdp_value desc) as 'rank',
    country_name,
    gdp_value,
    (gdp_value - 0) as gdp_test,
    average,
    (gdp_value - average) as difference
from merged
group by country_name, gdp_value, average
order by gdp_value desc;
```

Even if you don't totally like this query, you might try something similar where you use a subquery to fix `gdp_value` once.

Comment: okay thank you! just a little follow-up question: it's a problem with my dataset or it always works like this?

Comment: Yes, it is likely something going on with the data type of that column. I'm not sure exactly whats happening but probably if you change the type of the column itself in that table, you wont have to constantly be casting it every time you use it.